# Can we use binomial 'wine and dine' even if we just eat usual?

Tags: idioms

This question came to my mind after reading a sub-chapter on my book about binomials. The book also defines each binomial to help the reader understand. Here's the sentence, by the way:

> She has to **wine and dine** important clients. [entertain/take out to restaurants]

According to [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dine), **dine** means to eat dinner. And we all know wine is an alcoholic drink. Now, what if they turn out don't even drink wines and it's lunchtime? Do we still use this binomial?

As you can see the definition of the binomial above, there's no mention about the time and what they serve, eat and drink. I've also read this binomial in the link I've provided above and Oxford defines it as an idiom that means:

> ​to go to restaurants, etc. and enjoy good food and drink; to
> entertain somebody by buying them good food and drink.

In conclusion, is it OK if someday I want to treat someone even if we don't drink wine and it isn't dinner time and say **wine and dine**? Does that still make sense and not awkward? Also, what if I go to a café, is it still proper to use this idiom/binomial?

Comment: IMO: Yes, if you are trying to get into their good graces.  This made me look up the definition of *schmooze*, and: "... so as to gain favor."  2 of the 3 example sentences at your link have this connotation.  Business schmoozing.

Comment: @stevesliva Thank you for your comment. If I don't mistakenly understand, it doesn't matter whether it's lunchtime, breakfast time, drink wine, water, as long as we take out to restaurants it's called wine and dine?

Comment: It doesn't matter what time of day it is or what specific foods and drinks are served. The idiom typically implies a venue fancier than the average cafe, but you can still use the term (perhaps with a touch of irony) about less fancy establishments.

Comment: Right, the whole point to “wine and dine” is that it’s a rhyme that means “attempt to impress the customer enough, over a meal, to entice them into doing business with you”.  You usually can’t accomplish that at McDonald’s.

Comment: The verb "dine" [doesn't necessarily mean eat dinner](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dine) (especially in set phrases like dine out, dine in, dine out on), although it does imply having a sizable meal not just a snack or light meal. If you offer to "wine and dine" someone, I would recommend you at least offer them wine with their meal. It also has connotations of schmoozing or seducing, so if you're buying a friend lunch it probably wouldn't fit, and if you offer it to a friend of the opposite sex, they might get the wrong idea.